# Why is transitioning font-size so choppy in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, animation

When applying a CSS transition between two different font sizes, the resulting animation is smooth in Firefox, but quite choppy in Chrome.

```
div {
    font-size: 87.5%;
    padding: .5em;
    margin: .5em;
    transition: font-size .25s ease-in-out .25s, 
                padding .25s ease-in-out .25s, 
                margin .25s ease-in-out .25s;
}

div:hover {
    font-size: 100%;
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/B7Zyp/2/ (hover over the box with the blue border)

Why is that? Is there a way to make the animation smooth in Chrome?

Comment: i think it's not the browsers' problem. First, each character needs to increase by a bit every time, the collection of pixel difference for many characters would be visible to eyes. Secondly, the break of each line forces words to switch line, and it will feel choppy.

Comment: @Daniel Cheung: So why is Firefox able to pull it off so much better than Chrome?

Comment: @Šime Vidas, well, it gave difference for me (a rather old chrome [18.0.xx] on ubuntu) but fair enough. Deleted this unuseable answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Chrome currently doesn't use DirectWrite for font rendering on Windows. Text isn't anti-aliased and as such font-sizes are rounded (to the nearest integer?).

They are working on it though. See [this comment](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=137692#c109) on the related bug ticket and especially the attachment:

[image: Smooth font scaling]

If you enable DirectWrite with the proper flag, it should smoothly animate.

Comment: A little off-topic, but that's just about the best pangram I've ever seen, because you can actually imagine someone saying it in real life (although who keeps liquor in a jug?).

Comment: I've checked in Canary with DirectWrite flag set. Smooth as butter. Btw, I've heard rumors that this feature will be enabled by default in version 37.

Comment: Evidently the boyz at google with the big brainz haven't cracked this one yet. The chrome crew are starting to lag behind....